# How to make tasks that are visible to all private in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

We have a requirement wherein we need to make tasks private so that the owner of the task and the user to whom its assigned can only view it.
We have an open sharing model,OWD setting for all the objects is Public and activity is controlled by parent.
Any suggestion on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question does not conform to the expected format : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions . You should ask help to solve a real issue, not how to do something. Please, search by yourself and come back when you'll get stucked.

Comment: Actually we have to implement this requirement and we could not find any solution. So just trying to seek help if anybody else has also implemented this kind of functionality. There inputs would give us some direction.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make activities completely private then you will need to change your sharing model for the *Activity* object to *Private* and make sure *Grant Access Using Hierarchies* is unchecked.

This will ensure users cannot see tasks that aren't assigned to them.

Obviously if you want people higher in the role hierarchy to have access to tasks of users below them then make sure *Grant Access Using Hierarchies* is checked.